# UIImage RenderingMode : UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic vs UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal vs UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimage

I have come across the `UIImage` property `UIImageRenderingMode` which is introduced in iOS 7. But I don't get the differences among different `UIImageRenderingMode`s that are `UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic`, `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` and `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`.

I want to know the basic meaning of them and when/how to use them.

Comment: You can read about the properties here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/renderingMode

Comment: @NathanWride Read but could not understand as there is no example.

Comment: @Abizern, Filip, ling.s, Alberto, Laszlo I edited my question to fit in the SO format.

Comment: @NathanWride, "UIImageRenderingMode: Specifies the possible rendering modes for an image." Great help on that link. Not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150325085832/http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-beyers/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming) which explains `UIImageRenderingMode` with example.

**From tutorial :**

> UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate mode will replace all non-transparent colors on
>       a UIImage with the tint color. The entire background and any portion of the image
>       that you do not wish to render using the tint color must be completely transparent.
>
> UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. When this is applied the tint color is never
>       applied to the image so the original color is always used when rendering the
>       image.
>
> UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic automatically decides which rendering mode to use
>       based on where the image is being displayed. This is the default value for images.

Comment: Unfortunately, the tutorial link is now broken. Thanks that you copied the essential info here.

Comment: UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic is still not clear.

Comment: @ooops heeey I've figured it out, take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75615677/9353387