# `UIImage.RenderingMode.automatic` - how does it choose the actual mode?

Tags: uikit, uiimageview, uiimage

As per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/renderingmode/automatic), the rendering mode of `.automatic` for a `UIImage` leads to a behavior where the image is drawn "using the context’s default rendering mode".

What is this "context's rendering mode"? What is this "context"? How do I change its rendering mode?

Also, I have found another [antique SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200582/uiimage-renderingmode-uiimagerenderingmodeautomatic-vs-uiimagerenderingmodealw) about this matter, and the answer referred to some tutorial by Steven Beyers on `captechconsulting.com` and there it said:

```
UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic automatically decides which rendering mode to use based on where the image is being displayed. This is the default value for images.
```

What is the criteria of "where"? What makes a difference that drives the decision?

Overall, HOW does `UIImage.RenderingMode.automatic` decide how to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the surrounding display mechanism. A bar button item wants to tint the image as a template, but an image view wants to display the original image (for example). The automatic setting simply lets that behavior happen. Explicit settings override it.

Comment: For some reason, however, I am observing a behavior in my project where this is completely not the case... I have a UIButton with an image set to it. The Image is `Default`. Yet UIButton renders it as an original image, not a template.

Comment: It depends on the button type. That's why I didn't go into the details. (You'll notice I said nothing about UIButton.) Yours is probably a `.custom` button. See my book if you want a complete list.

Comment: Well, that seems like quite a vital omission... Yes, indeed, my button does appear to be of `type: .custom`.

Comment: I didn't "omit" anything. My answer doesn't attempt to give a complete list. The examples I give are right, and they are hedged with "for example" — deliberately. If you don't like that, don't accept it. I really don't care. You asked what "where" and "context" mean and I told you, illustrating the point with a few examples. Take it or leave it. As I say, all this info is available to you complete if you really want it.

Comment: Oh, I guess I really wasn't clear enough in the question then, as I really wanted to get something extensive. And with you answer, I assumed that it must be the complete answer and there is no more to the matter. Seems, it's just a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: Just unaccept my answer so I can delete it.

Comment: ??? no, why, it's good enough :)